# Does React Native Web Library support both PWA and Native APP?

Tags: reactjs, native

Sorry for this idioit question. I’m a beginner developer of React. I know this library https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web can compile React Native runs as PWA, so does it mean that I just need to write the codes one time for both iOS and Android app and PWA?

Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a little bit more complicated but +/- yes. Mostly you write one code and its working everywhere, but there are platform needs that are different and you need to cover it sometimes differently.